# What does the "Remember Me" checkbox in sign_in pages actually do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, remember-me

I am using devise authentication for rails.I added the remember me checkbox in my sign_in page by adding `devise :rememberable` in my User Model and configured my devise.rb to `config.remember_for = 2.weeks`,then added a form field for checkbox in my sign_in form like this
     `<% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
              <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
      <% end -%>`

I was wondering how actually this Remember Me checkbox works,can anyone throw some light into my doubt?

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/rememberable.rb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Rememberable manages generating and clearing token for remember the
>   user from a saved cookie. Rememberable also has utility methods for
>   dealing with serializing the user into the cookie and back from the
>   cookie, trying to lookup the record based on the saved information.
>   You probably wouldn't use rememberable methods directly, they are used
>   mostly internally for handling the remember token.

So it saves a cookie on the users computer, so that it persists between sessions rather than saving in session which won't (obviously).

From the [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Rememberable)